# Sorting Elements Based on CSS Class and Text not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sorting

I am trying to reorganize some information that is created by server-side code. The server is strapped for memory, and all sorting and displaying will need to be handled client-side with javascript/jquery. The html is along the lines of...

```
<div>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org" class="AccessSitesLinks true 1">Wikipedia Home</a>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold" class="AccessSitesLinks false 1">Wikipedia Gold</a>
    <a href="https://google.com" class="AccessSitesLinks true 2">Google Home</a>
    <a href="https://mail.google.com/" class="AccessSitesLinks false 2">Google Mail</a>
    <a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mushroom" class="AccessSitesLinks false 1">Wikipedia Mushrooms</a>
    <a href="https://facebook.com" class="AccessSitesLinks true 3">FaceBook Home</a>
    <a href="https://facebook.org/about" class="AccessSitesLinks false 3">FaceBook About</a>
</div>
```

Here is my fiddle in progress https://jsfiddle.net/ydc6ywuz/1/
The overall goal is to sort `AccessSitesLinks true` to be the root sites. Meaning any css class that is `false` should be appended to the root site based on the number after `false`. The best example is Wikipedia Home is `true` and `1`, sites like mushrooms and gold would be `false` and `1`.

This is not where my issue is. When I run this Javascript code. The sort works perfectly. but the href values remain the same. Despite them being correct in the Console.log portion.

```
    function setFields() {
    var sortSite = $('.AccessSitesLinks.true');
    var arr = sortSite.map(function(_, o) {
        return {
          t: $(o).text(),
          h: $(o).attr('href'),
          c: $(o).attr('class')
        };
      }).get();
      arr.sort(function(o1, o2) {
            return o1.t > o2.t ? 1 : o1.t <o2.t ? -1: 0;
      });

      sortSite.each(function(i, o) {
        console.log(i);
        $(o).text(arr[i].t);
        $(o).attr(arr[i].h);
        $(o).attr(arr[i].c);
        console.log(arr[i].h);
        console.log(arr[i].c);
      });
```

Edit: I tried doing `$(o).attr('href') = arr[i].h;` but this did not work Uncaught ReferenceError: invalid lef-hand side in assignment

Comment: It it possible you can amend the HTML in any way? This would be a lot easier if you use `data-*` attributes instead of classes for organising the elements.

Comment: When you're *setting* the attributes in the `.each()` loop, you have to provide the attribute name as well as the value.

Comment: What happens when you console.log(o) ?

Comment: @Pointy Yes! This was my error.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I'll look into data rather than using multiple css classes. Thanks

Comment: Side note: Probably best to compare strings via `localeCompare` instead of `>` and a pair of conditional operators: `return o1.t.localeCompare(o2.t);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These lines are the problem:

```
    $(o).attr(arr[i].h);
    $(o).attr(arr[i].c);
```

You need to provide the attribute names:

```
    $(o).attr("href", arr[i].h);
    $(o).attr("class", arr[i].c);
```

Comment: The issue now is Wikipedia Gold stays in the same spot, but that's because I haven't added the append logic. Thanks!

Comment: +50 in a minute! LoL

Comment: @PraveenKumar it's always super-simple ones like this too :)

Comment: Why can't I find such? LoL

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah. Makes up for the ones where you spend 45 minutes on a deeply-technical explanation which ultimately gets accepted (which is nice, means it helped the OP) and all of two people understood the tech enough to upvote. :-) And I know you've written those, to enjoy these too.